# TypeScript Json Array Type

Tags: typescript

I want to code class in TypeScript. But when I try to use **Jsons** in **Array** system crashing error because of TypeScript.

Here is my class;

```
class Api {
    url: string | undefined;
    credentials: Array<JSON> = [];
    headers: Array<JSON> = [];

    send(url: string, credentials: Array<JSON>, headers: Array<JSON>) {
        this.url = url;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    bearer(){
        this.headers.push({
            "Authorization" : "Bearer "
        })
    }
}

module.exports = new Api()
```

But in this codes when I try to set `bearer` headers I'm getting this error;

```
Argument of type '{ Authorization: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSON'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"Authorization"' does not exist in type 'JSON'.
```

How can I fix that?

I also try interface to fix it but it is not working too. Here is my simple interface;

```
interface credentialType {
    [x: string]: string
}
```

But it's also not working too

Edit;

Now I try;

```
interface credentialType {
    type: string;
    value: string
}
...
this.headers.push({
     type: 'Authen',
     value: 'Bearer'
})
```

It's also not working

Comment: JSON is a string representation of a JavaScript Object and is typed 100% as a `string`. `JSON` is not a standard type, so you need to show what that declaration is.

Comment: As mentioned above, `JSON` isn't what you think it is.  You need to decide what type credentials and headers are going to be; it *might* be as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXzAkm), but we need more information from you. When you say at the bottom "it's also not working" you're not saying *how* it's not working.  Please consider [edit]ing the question to provide a [mre].  Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what your JSON type is (which is the reason for this error), you have to change that to fix the incompatible type error. But, as a workaround, you can always use a cast if you're sure the type is right:

```
this.headers.push({ "Authorization": "Bearer " } as JSON)
```